# Google Earth Engine user limit exceeded error when applying a cloud mask on Sentinel-2 imagery

Tags: google-earth-engine, memoryerror

I am trying to create a 2 cloudless composites of Sentinel-2 imagery over a region of interest that is pretty cloudy. I found an example script in GEE that does a pretty aggressive cloud masking, however, when I tried to run it for a larger region I get this error:

> median Before: Tile error: User memory limit exceeded.

I tried increasing the 'tileScale' parameter to 16, but it didn't solve my issue. Is there a way to make this work?

Here is the code I tried so far

```js
// Imports
var sentinel_2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR"),
    s2c = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY"),
    aoi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[8.56076677823315, 51.679222745409525],
          [8.56076677823315, 50.572623056004275],
          [10.29111345792065, 50.572623056004275],
          [10.29111345792065, 51.679222745409525]]], null, false),
    s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");
    
// Dates
var eventDate = ee.Date('2018-01-18');

var AS = eventDate.advance(1, 'week');
var AE = AS.advance(3, 'month');

var BE = eventDate.advance(-1, 'week');
var BS = BE.advance(-3, 'month');

// Remove problematic bands that are missing in some images
var bandNames = sentinel_2.first().bandNames();
var bandsToRemove = ['MSK_CLDPRB', 'MSK_SNWPRB'];
var bandsToKeep = bandNames.removeAll(bandsToRemove);
var s2Sr = sentinel_2.map(function(image) {
  return image.select(bandsToKeep);
});


function indexJoin(collectionA, collectionB, propertyName) {
  var joined = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst(propertyName).apply({
    primary: collectionA,
    secondary: collectionB,
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: 'system:index',
      rightField: 'system:index'})
  }));
  // Merge the bands of the joined image.
  return joined.map(function(image) {
    return image.addBands(ee.Image(image.get(propertyName)));
  });
}

// Aggressively mask clouds and shadows.
function maskImage(image) {
  // Compute the cloud displacement index from the L1C bands.
  var cdi = ee.Algorithms.Sentinel2.CDI(image);
  var s2c = image.select('probability');
  var cirrus = image.select('B10').multiply(0.0001);

  // Assume low-to-mid atmospheric clouds to be pixels where probability
  // is greater than 65%, and CDI is less than -0.5. For higher atmosphere
  // cirrus clouds, assume the cirrus band is greater than 0.01.
  // The final cloud mask is one or both of these conditions.
  var isCloud = s2c.gt(65).and(cdi.lt(-0.5)).or(cirrus.gt(0.01));

  // Reproject is required to perform spatial operations at 20m scale.
  // 20m scale is for speed, and assumes clouds don't require 10m precision.
  isCloud = isCloud.focal_min(3).focal_max(16);
  isCloud = isCloud.reproject({crs: cdi.projection(), scale: 20});

  // Project shadows from clouds we found in the last step. This assumes we're working in
  // a UTM projection.
  var shadowAzimuth = ee.Number(90)
      .subtract(ee.Number(image.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE')));

  // With the following reproject, the shadows are projected 5km.
  isCloud = isCloud.directionalDistanceTransform(shadowAzimuth, 50);
  isCloud = isCloud.reproject({crs: cdi.projection(), scale: 100});

  isCloud = isCloud.select('distance').mask();
  return image.select('B2', 'B3', 'B4').updateMask(isCloud.not());
}


var s2_before = s2.filterBounds(aoi)
                  .filterDate(BS, BE)
                  
var s2c_before = s2c.filterBounds(aoi)
                    .filterDate(BS, BE)

var s2Sr_before = s2Sr.filterBounds(aoi)
                      .filterDate(BS, BE)

// Join the cloud probability dataset to surface reflectance.
var withCloudProbability_before = indexJoin(s2Sr_before, s2c_before, 'cloud_probability');
// Join the L1C data to get the bands needed for CDI.
var withS2L1C_before = indexJoin(withCloudProbability_before, s2_before, 'l1c');

// Map the cloud masking function over the joined collection.
var masked_before = ee.ImageCollection(withS2L1C_before.map(maskImage));

// Take the median, specifying a tileScale to avoid memory errors.
var median_before = masked_before.reduce(ee.Reducer.median(), 16);


var s2_after = s2.filterBounds(aoi)
                  .filterDate(AS, AE)
                  
var s2c_after = s2c.filterBounds(aoi)
                    .filterDate(AS, AE)

var s2Sr_after = s2Sr.filterBounds(aoi)
                      .filterDate(AS, AE)

// Join the cloud probability dataset to surface reflectance.
var withCloudProbability_after = indexJoin(s2Sr_after, s2c_after, 'cloud_probability');
// Join the L1C data to get the bands needed for CDI.
var withS2L1C_after = indexJoin(withCloudProbability_after, s2_after, 'l1c');

// Map the cloud masking function over the joined collection.
var masked_after = ee.ImageCollection(withS2L1C_after.map(maskImage));

// Take the median, specifying a tileScale to avoid memory errors.
var median_after = masked_after.reduce(ee.Reducer.median(), 16);



var visParams = {
  bands : ['B4_median', 'B3_median', 'B2_median'],
  min   : 0,
  max   : 3000
};

Map.addLayer(median_before, visParams, 'median Before');
Map.addLayer(median_after, visParams, 'median After')
// Map.addLayer(gt);
Map.centerObject(aoi);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reprojecting the images to 20 meters. That prevents any of Earth Engine's clever pyramiding to do it's work. Read up on it [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/scale). If you zoom in to about `20m/px` scale (use the inspector in the code editor to check), your layers render.

I would guess that `ee.Algorithms.Sentinel2.CDI()` also is quite processing intense. If you need to render these layers quickly, I'd suggest you try with a different cloud masking approach (maybe look at [this](https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/i63DS-Dg8Sg/m/Kc0knF9BBgAJ) for some ideas). Otherwise, you're stuck at viewing your layers zoomed-in, or export the images.

Comment: I tried to run it without specifying the scale, and I also tried exporting the image instead of displaying it but it didn't work. Less aggressive cloud masking methods don't give satisfactory results for the time period I am using. Anyway, thank you for the answer. I think this is a limitation of GEE and there's nothing I can do about it.